# Bangla font display problem in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unicode

To display unicode character is there need to install font in eclipse. I want to display bangla character but i am unable to display correctly.
If need to be install font in eclipse then what is the steps. plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install fonts in Eclipse. You install them for the operating system, and then you select them in preferences.